# Download a zip folder of selected files

Tags: server, wp-filesystem, ziparchive

I'm trying to download multiple files from the server in a zipped folder. Here is the code I have thus far:

**HTML**

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checked[]" value="<?php echo $path; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="download" value="Download Selected">
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
if(isset($_POST['download'])){
     $files = $_POST['checked'];
     foreach ($files as $file ) {

    if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/upload/folder/'. $file)){
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
        $full_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/bcg/wp-content/uploads/'. $file;
        download_url($full_path);
    }
    else {
        echo 'file doesnt exist';
    }   
  } 
}
```

Comment: I'm receiving an error stating `invalid argument provided for foreach`

Answer (score -1):

remove the brackets from your name="checked"
It should just be `<input type="checkbox" name="checked" value="<?php echo $path; ?>">`

Which would only return one value, so you cant do a foreach loop on one value. You need multiple input fields and then put those values into an array to use in the foreach loop

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the brackets don't need to be removed.